# Execute tests based on the diff

Tags: java, unit-testing, continuous-integration

I am working on a project called [collector-sahab](https://github.com/ASSERT-KTH/collector-sahab). It provides the execution difference of a patch. Following is a example:

[image: execution difference]

We run a specific set of tests that we know will at least cover the diff. Although we can run the entire test suite, we do not because it creates enormous traces and we run out of memory. I am looking for a **purely static** way to **find a subset of tests to run based on the diff**.

The most primitive way could be to find the test based on directory structure in java. For example, the test of `src/main/java/foo/Main.java` will be in `src/test/java/foo/MainTest.java`. However, in practice, this is a bold assumption, and we will also not be able to extend the approach to getting test methods instead of test classes.

Another way I looked up was to use [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html). However, when I tried to test it for some of classes in my source code, I did not get an expected result. For example, I ran the following command:

```bash
$ jdeps -verbose:class -R main/target/test-classes/PomTransformerTest.class
```

**Output**

```
PomTransformerTest.class -> java.base
PomTransformerTest.class -> not found
   PomTransformerTest                                 -> PomTransformerTest$Compiler                        not found
   PomTransformerTest                                 -> PomTransformerTest$Compiler$ModifyProperties       not found
   PomTransformerTest                                 -> PomTransformerTest$Surefire                        not found
   PomTransformerTest                                 -> java.lang.Object                                   java.base
```

I was expecting it also to mention [`PomTransformer`](https://github.com/ASSERT-KTH/collector-sahab/blob/main/main/src/main/java/io/github/chains_project/cs/preprocess/PomTransformer.java) in the output, but it did not and I am not sure why.

Anyway, any suggestion regarding different strategies would help. An explanation of why the expected class file (`PomTransfomer.class`) is not reported shall also help.